# Blocking I/O in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Newbie on Python and multiple threading.

I read some articles on what is blocking and non-blocking I/O, and the main difference seems to be the case that blocking I/O only allows tasks to be executed sequentially, while non-blocking I/O allows multiple tasks to be executed concurrently.

If that's the case, how blocking I/O operations (some Python standard built-in functions) can do multiple threading?

Answer (score 4):

Blocking I/O blocks the thread it's running in, not the whole process. (at least in this context, and on a standard PC)

Multithreading is not affected by definition - only current thread gets blocked.

Answer (score 2):

The global interpreter lock (in cpython) is a measure put in place so that only one active python thread executes at the same time. As frustrating as it can be, this is a good thing because it is put in place to avoid interpreter corruption.

When a blocking operation is encountered, the current thread yields the lock and thus allows other threads to execute while the first thread is blocked. However, when CPU bound threads (when purely python calls are made), only one thread executes no matter how many threads are running.

It is interesting to note that in python 3.2, code was added to mitigate the effects of the global interpreter lock. It is also interesting to note that other implementations of python do not have a global interpreter lock

Please not this is a limitation of the python code and that the underlying libraries may be still processing data.

Also, in many cases, when it comes to I/O, to avoid blocking,  a useful way to handle IO is using polling and eventing:

- **Polling** involves checking whether the operation would block and test whether there is data. For example, if you are trying to get
  data from a socket, you would use select() and poll()
- **Eventing** involves using callbacks in such a way that your thread is triggered when a relevant IO operation just occurred